# Deploy Laravel App

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel app and block the access to the others files like .env
I put all my laravel app in the www folder, and I add this htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I go to my domain url I have all the files.. seem like my htaccess is not working (he's on the Laravel app root)

[image: This is what I get when I go to my website url (this is the www foolder)]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method using only a `.htaccess` file placed in Laravel's root directory - e.g. alongside `app`, `bootstrap`, `config`, ... No changes whatsoever are necessary to your code.

The file rewrites all the requests so that requesting `/file.png` would in fact return `/public/file.png` and anything else is routed to `/public/index.php`. This also ensures that nothing outside the `public` folder can be accessed, thereby protecting any sensitive files like `.env` or `database/*`.

### The simple method

This method assumes that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set properly by your Apache server. Try this first and use the 2nd method only if it doesn't work on your server.

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on

# serve existing files in the /public folder as if they were in /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.+) /public/$1 [L]

# route everything else to /public/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
```

### The slightly more complicated method

If your server doesn't set DOCUMENT_ROOT properly, then you'll need to use an absolute path in RewriteCond. That is, an absolute path on the server's filesystem. You can get it by copying the following script to the directory where your Laravel installation will reside and visiting its URL - i.e. `http://example.com/get_doc_root.php`.

**`get_doc_root.php`**

```
<?php
echo getcwd();
```

This should result in something like `/var/www/example.com/web`. Use the following `.htaccess` file and replace `[[your path]]` with the actual path you got.

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on

# serve existing files in the /public folder as if they were in /
RewriteCond [[your path]]/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.+) /public/$1 [L]

# route everything else to /public/index.php
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
```

In our example case, the RewriteCond line would look like this:

```
RewriteCond /var/www/example.com/web/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
```

Comment: Okay this worrks but now all my css and js doesn't load (laravel is searching them at the root of my website)

Comment: I use syntax like this to get my css and js :  <link href="{{ asset('/css/datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> but this don't work, here is the output link :  http://domain.ovh/js/datepicker.js

Comment: But it's not a not found error, it's just the script don't load the error is "Failed to load"

Comment: change  <link href="{{ asset('/css/datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> to  <link href="{{ asset('css/datepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> without the trailing slash and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ this is strange the "asset" should go to the assets directory

Comment: Just in case, do you have your  DocumentRoot set to the public folder?